# How do I convert array of Objects into one Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
[ 
  { key : '11', value : '1100', $$hashKey : '00X' },
  { key : '22', value : '2200', $$hashKey : '018' }
];
```

How do I convert it into the following by JavaScript?

```
{
  "11": "1100",
  "22": "2200"
}
```

Comment: `[{key:"11", value:"1100"}, {key:"22", value:"2200"}].reduce(function(m,v){m[v.key] = v.value; return m;}, {})`

Comment: If you’re looking for the inverse of this: [Convert object to array of key–value objects like `{ name: "Apple", value: "0.6" }`](/q/47863275/4642212). If you’re looking for a variant where the result is another array of individual objects with a single property (e.g. `[ { "11": "1100" }, { "22": "2200" } ]`), see [How to convert array of key–value objects to array of objects with a single property?](/q/34744208/4642212).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```js
// original
var arr = [ 
  {key : '11', value : '1100', $$hashKey : '00X' },
  {key : '22', value : '2200', $$hashKey : '018' }
];

//convert
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  result[arr[i].key] = arr[i].value;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 333):

Tiny ES6 solution can look like:

```js
var arr = [{key:"11", value:"1100"},{key:"22", value:"2200"}];
var object = arr.reduce(
  (obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, { [item.key]: item.value }), {});

console.log(object)
```

Also, if you use object spread, than it can look like:

```
var object = arr.reduce((obj, item) => ({...obj, [item.key]: item.value}) ,{});
```

One more solution that is 99% faster is(tested on jsperf):

```
var object = arr.reduce((obj, item) => (obj[item.key] = item.value, obj) ,{});
```

Here we benefit from comma operator, it evaluates all expression before comma and returns a last one(after last comma). So we don't copy `obj` each time, rather assigning new property to it.

Comment: Loved the one! 
`var object = arr.reduce((obj, item) => (obj[item.key] = item.value, obj) ,{});`

Comment: is this one line faster or the conventional loop?

Comment: @Jeb50, conventional loop is the fastest, but not by much over the comma operator. Object.assign/spread operator is an order of magnitude slower: https://jsperf.com/comma-operator-js

Comment: You forgot to spread second object
`({...obj, ...{[item.key]: item.value}}) ,{});`

Comment: Thanks, wrapping this in an object actually is not required. I have fixed it.

Comment: This should be `var object = arr.reduce((obj, item) => { obj[item.key] = item.value; return obj} ,{});`

Comment: is that also 99% faster than Object.assign? Or just 99% faster than spread?

Answer (score 127):

This should do it:

```js
var array = [
    { key: 'k1', value: 'v1' },
    { key: 'k2', value: 'v2' },
    { key: 'k3', value: 'v3' }
];
var mapped = array.map(item => ({ [item.key]: item.value }) );
var newObj = Object.assign({}, ...mapped );
console.log(newObj );
```

---

One-liner:

```
var newObj = Object.assign({}, ...(array.map(item => ({ [item.key]: item.value }) )));
```

Answer (score 64):

I like the functional approach to achieve this task:

```
var arr = [{ key:"11", value:"1100" }, { key:"22", value:"2200" }];
var result = arr.reduce(function(obj,item){
  obj[item.key] = item.value; 
  return obj;
}, {});
```

**Note:** Last `{}` is the initial `obj` value for reduce function, if you won't provide the initial value the first `arr` element will be used (which is probably undesirable).

https://jsfiddle.net/GreQ/2xa078da/

Comment: and if the key is dynamic?

Comment: Well, you should know which property of the given item/object should be used as key and which as value no?
But if we assume that wfirst prop is always the key and second the value we could use a callback function like this:
    function(obj,item){
      var keys = item.keys();
        obj[item[keys[0]]] = item[keys[0]]; 
        return obj;
    }

Comment: Correction of callback above:
code
var obj = arr.reduce(function(obj,item){
  var keys = Object.keys(item);
  obj[item[keys[0]]] = item[keys[1]]; return obj;
},{});

Answer (score 55):

Using [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const array = [
    { key: "key1", value: "value1" },
    { key: "key2", value: "value2" },
];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(array.map(item => [item.key, item.value]));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This is cleaner and easier to read than the `Array.map` solutions imo

Comment: This is the cleanest way to do it IMHO, deserves more upvotes!

Answer (score 20):

you can merge array of objects in to one object in one line:

```
const obj = Object.assign({}, ...array);
```

Comment: this only works if the objects in the array have different keys, as such this will only keep the last object AFAICT.

Answer (score 17):

A clean way to do this using modern JavaScript is as follows:

```
const array = [
  { name: "something", value: "something" },
  { name: "somethingElse", value: "something else" },
];

const newObject = Object.assign({}, ...array.map(item => ({ [item.name]: item.value })));

// >> { something: "something", somethingElse: "something else" }
```

Answer (score 13):

Use [lodash](http://lodash.com)!

```
const obj = _.keyBy(arrayOfObjects, 'keyName')
```

Comment: this would have resulted in:  
{
   11:{ key : '11', value : '1100', $$hashKey : '00X' },
   22:{ key : '22', value : '2200', $$hashKey : '018' }
}
what u want to do instead is:
const obj= _.chain(arrayOfObjects)
            .keyBy('keyName')
            .mapValues('value')
            .value();

Answer (score 13):

Simple way using reduce

```
// Input : 
const data = [{key: 'value'}, {otherKey: 'otherValue'}];

data.reduce((prev, curr) => ({...prev, ...curr}) , {});

// Output
{key: 'value', otherKey: 'otherValue'}
```

More simple Using Object.assign

```
Object.assign({}, ...array);
```

Answer (score 4):

Update: The world kept turning. Use a functional approach instead.

---

*Previous answer*

Here you go:

```
var arr = [{ key: "11", value: "1100" }, { key: "22", value: "2200" }];
var result = {};
for (var i=0, len=arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    result[arr[i].key] = arr[i].value;
}
console.log(result); // {11: "1000", 22: "2200"}
```

Comment: Because that's how you solve this problem. About the naming for example: `array` is a reserved keyword so people use `arr` instead. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org):

```
var myArray = [
  Object { key="11", value="1100", $$hashKey="00X"},
  Object { key="22", value="2200", $$hashKey="018"}
];
var myObj = _.object(_.pluck(myArray, 'key'), _.pluck(myArray, 'value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Nearby 2022, I like this approach specially when the array of objects are dynamic which also suggested based on @AdarshMadrecha's test case scenario,**

```
const array = [ 
  { key : '11', value : '1100', $$hashKey : '00X' },
  { key : '22', value : '2200', $$hashKey : '018' }];
  
let obj = {};
array.forEach( v => { obj[v.key] = v.value }) //assign to new object
console.log(obj) //{11: '1100', 22: '2200'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [
  { key: "key1", value: "value1" },
  { key: "key2", value: "value2" },
];

let arr = {};

arr = array.map((event) => ({ ...arr, [event.key]: event.value }));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `let arr = array.map((event) => ({ [event.key]: event.value }));` is enough. Not sure what advantage this answer offers over existing answers though?

Comment: This actually doesn't convert the array of objects to an object which is the question asked. This will return an array of objects with the key and value mapped out. `[{"key1": "value1"},{"key2": "value2"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Was did yesterday

```
// Convert the task data or array to the object for use in the above form
 const {clientData} = taskData.reduce((obj, item) => {
 // Use the clientData (You can set your own key name) as the key and the 
 // entire item as the value
 obj['clientData'] = item
 return obj
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see so many variations in the answers above. This is how I did it using reduce:

```js
// original
var fields = [{
    fieldName: 'name',
    fieldValue: 'ABC',
    fieldType: 'string'
  },
  {
    fieldName: 'phone',
    fieldValue: '12345',
    fieldType: 'number'
  }
];

//convert
const result = fields.reduce((acc, field) => {
  acc[field.fieldName] = field.fieldValue;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to dynamically accept the above as a string and interpolate it into an object:

```
var stringObject = '[Object { key="11", value="1100", $$hashKey="00X"}, Object { key="22", value="2200", $$hashKey="018"}]';

function interpolateStringObject(stringObject) {
  var jsObj = {};
  var processedObj = stringObject.split("[Object { ");
  processedObj = processedObj[1].split("},");
  $.each(processedObj, function (i, v) {
      jsObj[v.split("key=")[1].split(",")[0]] = v.split("value=")[1].split(",")[0].replace(/\"/g,'');
  });

  return jsObj
}

var t = interpolateStringObject(stringObject); //t is the object you want
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3QKmX/1/

Answer (score -1):

```js
// original
var arr = [{
    key: '11',
    value: '1100',
    $$hashKey: '00X'
  },
  {
    key: '22',
    value: '2200',
    $$hashKey: '018'
  }
];

// My solution
var obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  obj[arr[i].key] = arr[i].value;
}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Comment: surely will keep in mind.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the mapKeys lodash function for that. Just one line of code!

Please refer to this complete code sample (copy paste this into repl.it or similar):

```
import _ from 'lodash';
// or commonjs:
// const _ = require('lodash');

let a = [{ id: 23, title: 'meat' }, { id: 45, title: 'fish' }, { id: 71, title: 'fruit' }]
let b = _.mapKeys(a, 'id');
console.log(b);
// b:
// { '23': { id: 23, title: 'meat' },
//   '45': { id: 45, title: 'fish' },
//   '71': { id: 71, title: 'fruit' } }
```