# Convert array of objects to just one object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I'm trying to turn this:

```
[ { '231634908': 137875 },
  { '388252786': 150004 },
  { '333624027': 144107 },
  { '382758108': 149729 },
  { '384113458': 149803 },
  { '384844004': 149848 },
  { '405877005': 150481 },
  { '405877005': 150481 } ]
```

Into this:

```
{
    '231634908': 137875,
    '388252786': 150004,
    '333624027': 144107,
    '382758108': 149729,
    '384113458': 149803,
    '384844004': 149848,
    '405877005': 150481,
    '405877005': 150481
}
```

Using underscore.

I tried

```
_.object(list);

_.object(_.keys(list), _.values(list));

_.object(_.keys(list[0]), _.values(list[0]));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert array of Objects into one Object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874555/how-do-i-convert-array-of-objects-into-one-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm no expert on underscore.js, but try this:

```
_.extend.apply(null, list);
```

One caveat: this will actually modify the first element of the list. If this is a concern you might want to use something like this instead:

```
_.extend.apply(null, [{}].concat(list));
```

Comment: If you wanted to make a function for this operation what would you call it? `extendArray`?

Comment: @ThomasReggi Probably `merge` or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

You want `_.reduce()`:

```
_.reduce(list, function(memo, o) {
  var k = Object.keys(o)[0];
  memo[k] = o[k];
  return memo;
}, {});
```

Comment: Some Underscore pro can probably point out that there are Underscore utilities to cut this in half :)

Comment: The body can be just [`return _.extend(memo, o);`](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9N2Bz/).

Answer (score 3):

A more elegant and native way to do it.

```
var a = [ { '231634908': 137875 },
{ '388252786': 150004 },
{ '333624027': 144107 },
{ '382758108': 149729 },
{ '384113458': 149803 },
{ '384844004': 149848 },
{ '405877005': 150481 },
{ '405877005': 150481 } ];

var b = {};

Array.prototype.forEach.call(a,function(elem) {
   var keys = Object.keys(elem);
   b[keys[0]] = elem[keys[0]];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One more native solution for case with multiple fields per object

```
var objects = [ { '231634908': 137875 },
  { '388252786': 150004 },
  { '333624027': 144107 },
  { '382758108': 149729 },
  { '384113458': 149803 },
  { '384844004': 149848 },
  { '405877005': 150481 },
  { '405877005': 150481 } ]


var singleObject = {};

for(var i in objects){
    var oKeys = Object.keys(objects[i]);
    for(var j in oKeys){
        singleObject[oKeys[j]] = objects[i][oKeys[j]];
    }
}

console.log(singleObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old, but it inspired me to do this natively one-line for multi key objects:

```
var arrayOfObjectsToCombine = [ { foo: 'bar', dog: 'cat' }, { baz: 'boom' } ];
arrayOfObjectsToCombine.reduce(function(done, obj) { Object.keys(obj).map( function(K) { done[K] = obj[K] } ); return done; }, {})
```

result:
{ foo: 'bar', dog: 'cat', baz: 'boom' }

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like this:

```js
let array = [ { '231634908': 137875 },
  { '388252786': 150004 },
  { '333624027': 144107 },
  { '382758108': 149729 },
  { '384113458': 149803 },
  { '384844004': 149848 },
  { '405877005': 150481 },
  { '405877005': 150481 } ]
  
const output = Object.assign({}, ...array)
console.log(output)
```