# is there an alternative on lodash to _.merge.apply(_, x); where x is an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I want to merge all the properties from an array of objects into one single object using lodash? I can iterate the array or call apply on _.merge:

```
const arr = [{1:1, 2:2},{3:3},{4:4}];

_.merge.apply(_, arr); //{1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4};
```

is there an alternative without using apply?

Comment: I don't think there it, but why don't you want to use `apply`?

Comment: there are a couple [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874555/how-to-convert-array-of-objects-into-one-object-in-javascript), is there a reason you want to avoid apply or lodash? EDIT: ah, i see, you strictly want to use lodash, nevermind this comment then

Comment: It was more out of curiosity with lodash API but seems like there is not a function that is doing that specifically. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/jeboya/3/edit?js,console)

You could use each and extend:

```
var o = {};
var arr = [{1:1, 2:2},{3:3},{4:4}];
_.each(arr, function(e) {
  _.extend(o, e);
});
```

or reduce:

```
var otherWay = _.reduce(arr, function(obj, next) {
  return _.extend(obj, next);
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like the prefect situation to use `[].reduce` (JS not lodash) :

```js
const arr = [{1:1, 2:2},{3:3},{4:4}];


const r = arr.reduce((ac,x) => Object.assign(ac,x),{})

console.log(r)
```

Comment: `Object.assign` returns the target object, so you could reduce (sic!) your answer even further: `arr.reduce((acc, x) => Object.assign(acc, x))`.

Comment: Unfortunately, no: it would mutate the original array, which may be highly unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

With ES6, you can do this:

```
const arr = [{1:1, 2:2},{3:3},{4:4}];

_.merge(...arr);
```

You should only do this if you're only targeting new browsers that support this, or if you're using a transpiler like Babel.

If you don't want to use ES6, then there's no reason to not use `.apply`. It's part of Javascript. Lodash has no need to re-invent this feature. [You shouldn't expect a library to do everything and replace the language itself.](http://amasad.me/2016/01/03/overcoming-intuition-in-programming/) The other loop-based answers (`.reduce`, `.each`, etc.) are needlessly less efficient than they need to be, since both `_.merge` and `Object.assign` support more than two parameters.

Comment: this! cooool... I am using babel so I can use that, nice, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I will give a very silly answer. Well thinking it over, since `Object.assign()` just makes shallow copies this might practically work out better if you are not fond of recursive operations.

```js
var arr = [{1:1, 2:2},{3:3},{4:4}],
 merged = JSON.parse(arr.reduce((s,o)=> s+JSON.stringify(o),"").replace(/}{/g,","));
document.write("<pre>" +JSON.stringify(merged,null,2) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) with [merge()](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) as the iterator and an empty object as the base object for the merge to prevent the mutation any mutation of the items of the array.

```js
var arr = [{1:1, 2:2},{3:3},{4:4}];

var result = _.reduce(arr, _.merge, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Note: The solution that you're using right now mutates the items of the array.