# Return Object from map() function not Array

Tags: javascript

Sorry if the title is misleading I'm not sure how to accurately describe what I am looking for.

I have an array `result` which I want to turn into multiple objects where each objects property is the field `Name Test` I need to keep my result.map method as I use it to merge `result` with `data`

```js
  result = [{
      "Name Test": "Yellow",
      Count: 124,

    },
    {
      "Name Test": "Black",
      Count: 124,
    },
    {
      "Name Test": "Blue",
      Count: 124,
    }
  ];

  data = [{
      "Name Test": "Yellow",
      pop: 1
    },
    {
      "Name Test": "Black",
      pop: 1
    },
    {
      "Name Test": "Blue",
      pop: 1
    }
  ];


result = result.map((obj1, index) => {
    const obj2 = data[index];
    return {
        [obj1["Name Test"].toUpperCase()]: {
            Count: obj1.Count,
            pop: obj2.pop,
        }
    };
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

This code returns an array of objects which is not what I want as I need to be able to use `result["YELLOW"]` later in my code. I therefore need the result to be in this format, with no arrays.

```
{  
   "YELLOW":{  
      "Count":124,
      "pop":1
   },
   "BLACK":{  
      "Count":124,
      "pop":1
   },
   "BLUE":{  
      "Count":124,
      "pop":1
   }
}
```

I hope this makes sense and I feel I am very close to what I want and just am missing something small, but every way I have tried to make this work turns into a syntax error.

Comment: You should look at [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert array of Objects into one Object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874555/how-do-i-convert-array-of-objects-into-one-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`map()` will always return an array.

- You should use `reduce()` and set accumulator to empty object `{}`
- Use the destructuring and spread syntax to isolate `Name Test` and other properties.
- Set the property of accumulator whose key is `"Name Test"` property of each object and its value is rest of the object.

```js
const arr = [{ "Name Test": "Yellow", Count: 124, pop: 1 }, { "Name Test": "Black", Count: 124, pop: 1 }, { "Name Test": "Blue", Count: 124, pop: 1 } ];

const res = arr.reduce((ac,{["Name Test"]:x,...rest}) => (ac[x] = rest,ac),{})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 4):

`map` will create a new array. So you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and pass an empty object in the accumulator

```js
let result = [{
    "Name Test": "Yellow",
    Count: 124,
    pop: 1
  },
  {
    "Name Test": "Black",
    Count: 124,
    pop: 1
  },
  {
    "Name Test": "Blue",
    Count: 124,
    pop: 1
  }
];

let newResult = result.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  // acc is accumulator which is the required object.
  // this will create a nee key in accumulator and will set its value
  acc[curr['Name Test'].toUpperCase()] = {
    Count: curr.Count,
    pop: curr.pop
  }
 return acc;
}, {}) // {} is accumulator object. This will hold the required keys and values

console.log(newResult)
```

Comment: Hi @brk, the reason I didnt use reduce to begin with is I merge together 2 arrays inside the map function https://jsfiddle.net/cqraohy5/1/ This is how this question looks with the merge but doesnt work with the reduce method

Comment: @DanielJ map can never return object.

Comment: I've edited my orginal question to clarify what I am asking @brk so in my case, do I need to do my merge with `map` then do the reduce method to reduce it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not available in MS browsers yet, (I think), but [`fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) is pretty nice for this. You can pass it an iterable or key.value pairs, such as the results from `map()`.

```js
let result = [{"Name Test": "Yellow",Count: 124,pop: 1},{"Name Test": "Black",Count: 124,pop: 1},{"Name Test": "Blue",Count: 124,pop: 1}];
let data = [{"Name Test": "Yellow",pop: 1},{"Name Test": "Black",pop: 1},{"Name Test": "Blue",pop: 1}];

let o = Object.fromEntries(result.map(({'Name Test':n, ...o}) => ([n, o])))
let d = Object.fromEntries(result.map(({'Name Test':n, ...o}) => ([n, o])))
 
console.log(Object.assign(o, d))
```