# from array of objects to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like this:

```js
array = [{profile: 'pippo'}, {profile: 'mickey'}]
```

and I would like to transform it to this:

```js
object = {0: 'pippo', 1: 'mickey'}
```

Comment: `array.reduce((o,x,i)=>(o[i]=x.profile,o),{});`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert array of Objects into one Object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874555/how-do-i-convert-array-of-objects-into-one-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a short `reduce`:

```js
const array = [{profile: 'pippo'}, {profile: 'mickey'}]

const output = array.reduce((a, o, i) => (a[i] = o.profile, a), {})
console.log(output)
```

Or even use `Object.assign`:

```js
const array = [{profile: 'pippo'}, {profile: 'mickey'}]

const output = Object.assign({}, array.map(o => o.profile))
console.log(output)
```

However, your output is in the same format as an array, so you could just use `map` and access the elements by index (it really just depends on the use case):

```js
const array = [{profile: 'pippo'}, {profile: 'mickey'}]

const output = array.map(o => o.profile)
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

Extract the profiles value with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) into an object:

```js
const array = [{profile: 'pippo'}, {profile: 'mickey'}]

const result = { ...array.map(o => o.profile) }

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) it would be very easy. there you have how it works and a working example.

```js
array = [{
  profile: 'pippo'
}, {
  profile: 'mickey'
}]


const finalObj = array.reduce((accum, cv, index) => {
  accum[index] = cv['profile']
  return accum;
}, {})

console.log(finalObj)
```