# Remove duplicates when appending option to Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have dynamically created dropdowns and populating them with data from a json array.

Data:

```
data = [{hello: 'abc', asd: '123', fgh: '345' }, 
{hello: 'sdf', asd: '456', fgh: 'df' }, 
{hello: 'ty', asd: '789', fgh: '345675' },
{hello: 'qwe', asd: '123', fgh: '987' }]
```

array of keys (for the data I need in the dropdown): `arr = ['asd', 'fgh']`

Creation of dropdown:

```
arr.forEach(c => {
   $('div').append(`
     <div class='float-left'>
     <p>${c}</p>
     <select id='${c}'></select>
    </div>`);
});
```

To populate the dropdowns:

```
arr.forEach(o => {
   data.forEach(strs => {
      if (strs[o] != null) {
         $(`#${o}`).append(`<option value='${strs[o]}'>${strs[o]}</option>`);
      }
   });
});
```

I am able to populate the dropdowns. How do I populate the dropdowns with **NO DUPLICATES**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of each of the values of the object indexes specified by `arr` and de-duplicate that before using it to add options. Note I've combined your two `forEach` loops; doing so requires adding an `id` to the top-level `div`. If you don't want to do that you will need to split them apart again.

```js
data = [{hello: 'abc', asd: '123', fgh: '345' }, 
{hello: 'sdf', asd: '456', fgh: 'df' }, 
{hello: 'ty', asd: '789', fgh: '345675' },
{hello: 'qwe', asd: '123', fgh: '987' }]

arr = ['asd', 'fgh']

arr.forEach(o => {
  $('div#top').append(`
     <div class='float-left'>
     <p>${o}</p>
     <select id='${o}'></select>
    </div>`);
  let vals = data.map(strs => strs[o]);
  vals.filter((v, i) => v !== null && vals.indexOf(v) === i)
      .forEach(v => $(`#${o}`).append(`<option value='${v}'>${v}</option>`));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='top'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle the duplicate `<select>` elements you need to not append to the generic 'div' selector. Instead I use a named class `.container`.

To handle duplicate `<option>`s I would use the array method `.some()`

```js
data = [{hello: 'abc', asd: '123', fgh: '345' }, 
{hello: 'sdf', asd: '456', fgh: 'df' }, 
{hello: 'ty', asd: '789', fgh: '345675' },
{hello: 'qwe', asd: '123', fgh: '987' }]

arr = ['asd', 'fgh']

arr.forEach(c => {
   $('.container').append(`
     <div class='float-left'>
     <p>${c}</p>
     <select id='${c}'></select>
    </div>`);
});

arr.forEach(o => {
   data.forEach(strs => {
      if (strs[o] != null) {
      
      const alreadyHasThis = $(`#${o} option`).toArray().some(option => option.value === strs[o]);
                  
      if(!alreadyHasThis){
          $(`#${o}`).append(`<option value='${strs[o]}'>${strs[o]}</option>`);
      }
     
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first use a temporary array with your selected data, and use `[... new Set(data)]` to remove duplicates. Then use this array to build your control.

```js
data = [{hello: 'abc', asd: '123', fgh: '345' }, 
{hello: 'sdf', asd: '456', fgh: 'df' }, 
{hello: 'ty', asd: '789', fgh: '345675' },
{hello: 'qwe', asd: '123', fgh: '987' }]

arr = ['asd', 'fgh']

var selects = arr.reduce((r, e) => (r[e] = [... new Set(data.map(d => d[e]))], r), {});

console.log(selects)

var html = ""
for (sel of arr) {
  html += `<div class='float-left'>${sel} <select id='${sel}'>`;
  for (data of selects[sel]) 
    html += `<option value='${data}'>${data}</option>`;
  html += `</select></div>`;
}
document.querySelector("div").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

References: [How do I convert array of Objects into one Object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874555/how-do-i-convert-array-of-objects-into-one-object-in-javascript) https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-remove-array-duplicates-in-es6-5daa8789641c