# How to convert Array of Object into Object in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lodash, codegen

[GetQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwfDP.png)

sample data from getquery graphql generated api

```
{
    id: '',
    name: '',
    regions: [
      {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        districts: [
          {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            locations: [{ id: '', city: '', division: '', street: '' }],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
```

convert it to

```
{
  id: '',
  name: '',
  regions: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    districts: {
      id: '',
      name: '',
      locations: { id: '', city: '', division: '', street: '' },
    },
  },
}
```

I already tried to convert it by using this code

```
const data = dataGetOrganization?.AllCountries

const result = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = {
    ...data[key],
    _styles: {
      root: { overflow: 'hidden' },
    },
  }
  return acc
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert array of Objects into one Object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874555/how-do-i-convert-array-of-objects-into-one-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you never have more than one region, one district and one location?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var newObj = Object.assign({}, ...(array.map(item => ({ [item.key]: item.value }) )));
```