# How to properly use clearInterval

Tags: javascript, html, clearinterval

I want this reset button to clear/reset the timer. I need it to reset because when the user presses the start button more then once it set´s two timers one that was started previously and the one that was just started.

I´m going to use clearInterval to fix this.

Here is my timer:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function () {
      minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
      seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

      if (--timer < 0) {
          timer = duration;
      }
      function resetTimer(){
          clearInterval(timer);
      }
  }, 1000);
}

function start5Timer() {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
      display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<body>
    <div><span id="time">05:00</span> minutes!
    <button onclick="start5Timer()">start</button>
    <button onclick="resetTimer()">reset</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It isn´t a JS fiddle but Here is a link to my code with the w3school v3.6 tryit editor:  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJQGNII3DAM6

Comment: And yes, don't use w3schools as a learning resource.

Comment: You need to set a variable to the result of calling `setInterval` and pass that variable to `clearInterval`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: @HereticMonkey When I press start more then one time the timer shows the previous and current timer set. I now realize that this might not help solve the problem should I use a display property, like after they press reset the timer won't show the previous timer set and only the current? But then I might have to use the display property multiple times, because the user presses start for the same timer multiple times. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: If you don't want multiple concurrent timers running, disable the start button while a timer is running. Function `resetTimer` must be pulled into a scope where it is visible by the reset button click handler. When starting a timer the timer ID must be stored in a variable, to be used by the `resetTimer` function.

Comment: There are a cornucopia of questions and answers on this site about stopping/resetting timers. [How do I reset the setInterval timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19874555/215552), for instance, must have come up in a search. The question is, why have two buttons? Have your start button become a reset button. Have the click handler check to see if it's running and if it is, reset it, otherwise, start one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timerId in the global scope. Set it's value when the interval starts and use the timerId to clear the interval and start a new timer starting from 05:00

```
<html>

  <body>
    <div><span id="time">05:00</span> minutes!
      <button onclick="start5Timer()">start</button>
      <button onclick="resetTimer()">reset</button>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
    let timerId;
    function startTimer(duration, display) {
      var timer = duration,
        minutes, seconds;
      timerId = setInterval(function() {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
          timer = duration;
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
    
     function resetTimer() {
          clearInterval(timerId);
          start5Timer();
        }

    function start5Timer() {
      var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
      display = document.querySelector('#time');
       startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
    };

  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks like the timer loops, do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: If you want to just clear the interval and not reset it back to its original value, then you can avoid it by not calling start5timer inside the resetTimer function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a timer implementation using unidirectional data-flow and immutable state.

There are three actions: start, reset and tick. When dispatched to the store, the state is updated.

The timer controls its own rendering using `requestAnimationFrame`.

```js
function createStore(initialState, reducers) {
  let state = Object.freeze(initialState)
  const reducerMap = reducers.reduce(
    (p, { type, reducer }) => (p[type] ? p[type].push(reducer) : (p[type] = [reducer]), p), {})

  function dispatch(action, ...args) {
    state = reducerMap[action].reduce((p, c) => c(p, ...args), state)
  }

  return {
    dispatch,
    getState() {
      return state
    }
  }
}

const toTwoDigitString = (n) => (n + "").padStart(2, "0")

const formatForDisplay = (seconds) =>
  `${toTwoDigitString(~~(seconds / 60))}:${toTwoDigitString(
    ~~(seconds % 60)
  )} minutes`

const tick = (store) =>
  store.getState().elapsedSeconds >= store.getState().durationSeconds
    ? clearInterval(store.getState().timerId)
    : store.dispatch(ACTION_TICK)

const startTimer = (store) => {
  if (store.getState().timerId !== null) return
  const timerId = setInterval(() => tick(store), 1000)
  store.dispatch(ACTION_START, timerId)
}

const resetTimer = (store) => {
  clearInterval(store.getState().timerId)
  store.dispatch(ACTION_RESET)
}

const render = ({ displayEl, durationSeconds, elapsedSeconds }) =>
  (displayEl.innerHTML = formatForDisplay(durationSeconds - elapsedSeconds))

const ACTION_START = "ACTION_START"
const ACTION_RESET = "ACTION_RESET"
const ACTION_TICK = "ACTION_TICK"

const reducerStart = {
  type: ACTION_START,
  reducer(state, timerId) {
    return {
      ...state,
      timerId
    }
  }
}

const reducerReset = {
  type: ACTION_RESET,
  reducer(state) {
    return {
      ...state,
      timerId: null,
      elapsedSeconds: 0
    }
  }
}

const reducerTick = {
  type: ACTION_TICK,
  reducer: (state) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      elapsedSeconds: ++state.elapsedSeconds
    }
  }
}

function createTimer({ selector, durationSeconds }) {
  const timerEl = document.querySelector(selector)

  const initialState = {
    timerId: null,
    displayEl: timerEl.querySelector("#time"),
    durationSeconds,
    elapsedSeconds: 0
  }

  const store = createStore(initialState, [
    reducerStart,
    reducerReset,
    reducerTick
  ])

  const start = () => startTimer(store)
  const reset = () => resetTimer(store)

  timerEl.querySelector("button#start").addEventListener("click", start)
  timerEl.querySelector("button#reset").addEventListener("click", reset)

  const previousState = null
  ;(function renderLoop() {
    if (previousState !== store.getState()) render(store.getState())
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop)
  })()
}

createTimer({ selector: "#timer", durationSeconds: 2 * 5 })
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #dc1a1a !important;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">
  <span id="time">The time is:</span>
  <button id="start">start</button>
  <button id="reset">reset</button>
</div>
```