# Extract javascript array value as Object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following array with objects

```
objectArray = [{name: “E-mail”, data_type: “text”}, {name: “Number”, data_type: “text”}, {name: “Person”, data_type: “text”}]
```

I need to extract just the `name` prop from the array object as a key in a new object like this:

```
counterObject = {E-mail: 0, Number: 0, Person: 0}
```

I've tried to `map` the array like this

```
objectArray((elem) => {
                return {[elem.name]:0};
            }))
```

and I've got the following result:

```
[{Text: 0}, {Number: 0}, {E-mail: 0}, {Person: 0}, {Upload: 0}, {Date: 0}, {Link: 0}]
```

Comment: Smart-quotes in code make it harder for people to work with your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert array of Objects into one Object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874555/how-do-i-convert-array-of-objects-into-one-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [{ name: "E-mail" }, { name: "Number" }, { name: "Person" }];

const result = {};
arr.forEach(obj => result[obj.name] = 0);

console.log(result);
```

`reduce` is another solution, but IMO it's less readable, and has the disadvantage of continually creating/shallow-copying the accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for this:

```js
const objectArray = [{name: "E-mail", data_type: "text"}, {name: "Number", data_type: "text"}, {name: "Person", data_type: "text"}];

const result = objectArray.reduce((res, o) => ({ ...res, [o.name]: 0 }), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It works, thank you! 
I didn't thinked about `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
let extractedKeys = Object();

for(i = 0; i < objectArray.length ; i++){

     extractedKeys[objectArray[i]['name']] = 0;
}

console.log(extractedKeys);
```