# How do I convert Array of object to Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I am trying to convert array of objects in to new object

I have this

```
const filter = [
    {
      fieldName: "userid"
      fieldValue: "12345"
    },
    {
      fieldName: "username"
      fieldValue: "myname"
    }
];
```

Need output like this

```
   const filterOut = {
           userid: "12345",
           username: "myname"
    }
```

Comment: What about:

out = filter[1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert array of Objects into one Object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874555/how-do-i-convert-array-of-objects-into-one-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```js
const filter = [
    {
      fieldName: "userid",
      fieldValue: "12345"
    },
    {
      fieldName: "username",
      fieldValue: "myname"
    }
];

const filterOut = filter.reduce((acc, { fieldName, fieldValue }) => ({ ...acc, [fieldName]: fieldValue }), {});

console.log(filterOut);
```

Answer (score 0):

Math the array to an array of `[key, value]` entries, and convert the entries to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const filter = [{"fieldName":"userid","fieldValue":"12345"},{"fieldName":"username","fieldValue":"myname"}];

const filterOut = Object.fromEntries(
  filter.map(o => [o.fieldName, o.fieldValue])
);

console.log(filterOut);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Guys, Appreciate it      

Answer (score 0):

A simple function to do this conversion:

```js
function fieldArrayToObject(fields) {
  if (Array.isArray(fields)) {
     let obj = {};
     fields.forEach(field => {
       obj[field.fieldName] = field.fieldValue;
     });
     return obj;
  }
  return null;
}
```