# Cleanest way to convert this array into a single object?

Tags: javascript

Just looking for the cleanest way to turn the following array into the following object format. Thanks a lot

```
const item = [
  { address: '123 fake street' },
  { loan: 'no' },
  { property: 'no' }
]

const obj = {
    address: '123 fake street',
    loan: 'no',
    property: 'no'
}
```

Comment: Check this answer.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67584636/7785337

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert the array of objects into a single object.

```js
const item = [
  { address: '123 fake street' },
  { loan: 'no' },
  { property: 'no' }
]

const obj = Object.assign({}, ...item);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) would be one clean way to convert the array to an object.

```
const item = [
  { address: '123 fake street' },
  { loan: 'no' },
  { property: 'no' }
]

let obj = item.reduce((pre, cur)=>{
    return {...pre, ...cur};
}, {});
    
// Result: obj={address: '123 fake street', loan: 'no', property: 'no'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple `for...of` loop to iterate over the array, and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to extract the key/value. Then just update an empty object with that information

```js
const item = [
  { address: '123 fake street' },
  { loan: 'no' },
  { property: 'no' }
];

const obj = {};

for (const el of item) {
  const [[key, value]] = Object.entries(el);
  obj[key] = value;
}

console.log(obj);
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score -1):

```
const arr = [{key:"address", value:"123 fake street"},{key:"loan", value:"no"},{key:"property", value:"no"}];
const object = arr.reduce(
  (obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, { [item.key]: item.value }), {});

console.log(object)
```

One more solution which is 99% faster (jsperf tested)

```
const object = arr.reduce((obj, item) => (obj[item.key] = item.value, obj) ,{});
```

and More simplest solution

```
// original
const arr = [ 
  {key:"address", value:"123 fake street"},
  {key:"loan", value:"no"},
  {key:"property", value:"no"}
];

//convert
const result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  result[arr[i].key] = arr[i].value;
}

console.log(result);
```