# map json object to key/value objects

Tags: javascript

I have a json as follows.

```
order = 
    {
        requests: [
            { code: 'T1', id: '123', requestStatus: 'request' },
            { code: 'T2', id: '321', requestStatus: 'request' }
        ]
    }
```

I want to get an object with key/value pair as follows.

```
ids['123']='T1'
ids['321']='T2'
```

I tried with this.

```js
const order = 
{
    requests: [
        { code: 'T1', id: '123', requestStatus: 'request' },
        { code: 'T2', id: '321', requestStatus: 'request' }
    ]
};

let id = order['requests'].map((r) => [r.code] = r.id);

console.log(ids['123'] == 'T1');
console.log(ids['321'] == 'T2');
```

I am getting an error 'object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))'.

Can someone show me how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Requests is apparently null by the time you call map

Comment: Is `order.requests` assigned in an async function? If so, you're probably not awaiting it properly.

Comment: `(r: { code: string, id: string })` doesn't seem to be valid syntax; did you mean `{r: { code: string, id: string }}`?

Comment: Definitely a dupe, just need to find it, but `const ids = Object.fromEntries( order.requests.map(({ code, id }) => [id, code]));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert array of Objects into one Object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874555/how-do-i-convert-array-of-objects-into-one-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const order = {
  requests: [
    {code: 'T1', id: '123', requestStatus: 'request'},
    {code: 'T2', id: '321', requestStatus: 'request'}
  ]
};


let ids = {};
order['requests'].forEach(({code, id}) => ids[id] = code);

console.log(ids);
```

prints

```js
{ '123': 'T1', '321': 'T2' }
```

Note that I use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to unpack objects in the lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array.reduce` method:

```
order = {
  requests: [
    {code: 'T1', id: '123', requestStatus: 'request'},
    {code: 'T2', id: '321', requestStatus: 'request'}
  ]
}

const ids = order.requests.reduce((acc, req) => {
    // Add each property to the accumulator
    acc[req.id] = req.code;
    return acc;
}, {}); // Start with an empty object
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const order = {
  requests: [
    { code: 'T1', id: '123', requestStatus: 'request' },
    { code: 'T2', id: '321', requestStatus: 'request' }
  ]
};

const ids = {};
order.requests.forEach((request) => {
  ids[request.id] = request.code;
});
```

Comment: Have you copied the other answer?

Comment: I saw it after posting :|||

Comment: The time difference is 18 minutes. You should check other answers before you post your answer. Duplicate answers are not helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry that I wasted your time and didn't have time to read the other answers that were not accepted

Comment: If you don't have the time to check if your answer is already posted (there were two answer at that time), you shouldn't post an answer.

Comment: read again.....